# ng-repeat : output only unique first letter filter

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat on a dataset that I loop using ng-repeat:

```
<div id="songlist">
<p ng-repeat="data in output">{{data.nm}}</p>
</div>
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
<div id="songlist">
<p>Across The Universe</p>
<p>Blackbird</p>
<p>Baby In Black</p>
</div>
```

What i'd like to do is only output the unique first letter of each song name so that it would output:

```
<div id="songlist">
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Just putting in my two cents, ssmithstone's answer seems the best to me so far since you're not having to continuously reprocess the data every time a digest occurs.  Process the data when you know it changes if it's a costly operation.  If it isn't a huge amount of data then a filter could work, so depends on your use case I guess.

Comment: thanks for the input shaunhusain. i will try to repurpose claydiffrient's filter to create a new model and see how that performs. my main model is huge so creating a new model with just the letters would probably work better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an Angular filter solution then this will probably do it for you:

```
app.filter('firstLetterFilter', [function () {
 return function (list) {
    var firstLetters = [];
    list.forEach(function (item) {
      var firstLetter = item.nm.charAt(0);
      if (firstLetters.indexOf(firstLetter) === -1) {
        firstLetters.push(firstLetter);
      }
    });
    return firstLetters;
  }
}]);
```

It's working at this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RS0kSNj3sERayJBjDqF4

Comment: Thanks claydiffrient...nice and clean solution!

Answer (score 1):

create a new model from a method that contains the required functionality and then use the ng-repeat to iterate over that object

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/aj2mass5mZTM3VmGjSIk?p=preview

Please see the above plunker with filter

```
 <div class="item" ng-repeat="person in people | firstUnique">

    app.filter('firstUnique',function() {
      return function( persons) {
        var filtered = [];
    var p = {};
        angular.forEach(persons, function(item) {
          var first = item.name.substring(0,1);
          if(p[first]){

          }else{
            p[first] = first;
            filtered.push({name :first});
          }
        });

        return filtered;
      };

    });
```

Comment: Nice solution.  Although, it doesn't take into account the order of the letters.  I'm not sure if the OP cares about that, but it is a slight consideration.